# How to format text loaded from file?

Tags: c#, text, file-io, string-formatting

I have a `.htm` file like template and i want to read the contents and update a specific part of the page.
The file has a typical html format where in some point i added the special string `{0}` in order to be able to format it. Also i made sure that the `{0}` is the only one occurrence.

I've tried the following, but throws me an exception `Input string was not in a correct format`:

```
sText = @File.ReadAllText("template.htm"));
formated = string.Format(sText, "Add some additional text here");
```

Which would be the correct way to implement this?

Thanks

**Edit**

The contents of the variable (debug) start like this:

```
    "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\r\n    <title></title>\r\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\r\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\r\nbody {\r\n  margin: 0;\r\n  mso-line-height-rule: exactly;\r\n  padding: 0;\r\n  min-width: 100%;\r\n}\r\ntable {\r\n  border-collapse: collapse;\r\n  border-spacing: 0;\r\n}\r\ntd {\r\n  padding: 0;\r\n  vertical-align: top;\r\n}\r\n.spacer,\r\n.border {\r\n  font-size: 1px;\r\n  line-height: 1px;\r\n}\r\n.spacer {\r\n  width: 100%;\r\n}\r\nimg {\r\n  border: 0;\r\n  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;\r\n}\r\n.image {\r\n  font-size: 0;\r\n  Margin-bottom: 24px;\r\n}\r\n.image img {\r\n  display: block;\r\n}\r\n.logo {\r\n  mso-line-height-rule: at-least;\r\n}\r\n.logo img {\r\n  display: block;\r\n}\r\nstrong {\r\n  font-weight:
```

---

**Edit 2**

For just in case for people searching something like this i actually found something called [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) and looks exactly what i need!

Comment: I have doubt that template.htm contain some character that cause this issue.

Comment: did u try replace function sText.Replace("{0}", "new string");?  html would be having some doublequotes etc.. its not able to recognize I guess

Comment: @dotnetstep Why do you have doubt? It's not that hard to have `'{'` or `'}'` in a html file, e.g. in a javascript function or in a style.

Comment: As for why `string.Format` does not work: the part of your style `{\r\n margin:(...);\r\n}` (among others) is treated as a format item, and it does not conform to format item syntax.

Comment: Use RegEx for finding, appending and replacing at desired location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format string in string.Format() looks for many characters/patterns to do its work. It is (generally) very dangerous to use "arbitrary" text there.
In your case a much better (safer) solution would be:

```
sText = @File.ReadAllText("template.htm"));
formated = sText.Replace("{0}", "Add some additional text here");
```

Comment: Using this technique, it is better to use a marker which is very,very unlikely to occur in normal text like "<<Pattern0>>"